# Finite conjugacy classes

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be an infinite group. Let $N_0$ be the set of all $x\in G$ for which the conjugacy class $\{y^{-1}xy: y\in G\}$ is a finite set. Clearly $N_0$ is a normal subgroup. Iteratively, form an ascending transfinite sequence by

- for $n$ a non-limit ordinal, let $N_n\subseteq G$ be the set of all $x\in G$ for which $xN_{n-1}\in G/N_{n-1}$ has finite conjugate class.
- for $\omega$ a limit ordinal, $N_{\omega} = \bigcup_{\alpha<\omega} N_{\alpha}$.

There are two possibilities: either $(N_\alpha)$ stops at $G$, or at a proper subgroup $G^{FC}$ of $G$. For convenience, let's call (only for this post) $G^{FC}$ the *[FC]-kernel* of $G$, and $G$ a *hyper-[FC] group* if $G=G^{FC}$. A simple observation is that $G/G^{FC}$ is an [[ICC]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_conjugacy_class_property) group. Let's call $G^{FC}$ a *minimal [FC]-kernel* if whenever $N_0\subseteq H\subseteq G$ is another normal subgroup for which $G/H$ is [ICC], we have $H\supseteq G^{FC}$.

I apologize if the questions below are elementary for MO.

**Q0:** Could you please point me to a reference where I can find the proper terminology for the made-up names *hyper-[FC] group* & *[FC]-kernel*?

**Q1:** Is $G^{FC}$ a hyper-[FC] group in itself?

**Q2:** Is $G^{FC}$ always *minimal* in the sense above?

Thanks in advance.

---

**edit:** Following Sean Eberhard's suggestion, I've just came across the book "Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups" by Robinson. The terminology he used in his book is *FC-Hypercenter* for $G^{FC}$, and *FC-Hypercentral* if $G=G^{FC}$. It is a big deal(!) that the made-up names by yours truly were a close call after all.. The book explains various central series in detail for those who are curious about the similarities in the construction & the properties of X-hypercenters, and more..

Comment: Why is $N_0$ clearly a subgroup?

Comment: @LSpice Let $O(x)=\{gxg^{-1}:g\in G\}$. For $x,y\in N_0$ and all $g\in G$, 
$gxy^{-1}g^{-1} = gxg^{-1}(gyg^{-1})^{-1}\in O(x)O(y)^{-1}$. So $O(xy^{-1})\subseteq O(x)O(y)^{-1} \Rightarrow |O(xy^{-1})|\leq |O(x)||O(y)|$.

Comment: $N_0$ is called the FC-center of $G$. https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/FC-center

Comment: @SeanEberhard thanks a bunch. I wonder if $(N_\alpha)$ is called [FC]-central sequence, analogous to central sequences. My made up name hyper-[FC] was inspired by the same anology. I'm asking for the right terminology so that I can use them as keywords for literature search.

Comment: @LSpice the FC-center $\mathrm{FC}(G)$ is a "clearly" subgroup because it consists of elements whose centralizer has finite index.

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452353/finite-conjugacy-classes#comment1171590_452353), thanks.  @‍OnurOktay also [explained](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452353/finite-conjugacy-classes#comment1169796_452353), along essentially similar lines.  I was hung up on the (usually) inequality of the orbit of $x y^{-1}$ with the product of the orbits of $x$ and $y^{-1}$, and it didn't occur to me that a bound was good enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Q0:** For references try starting with Robinson's *A course in the theory of groups*, starting around 14.5.5. There the FC center is defined and some characterizations are given for FC groups (groups with finite conjugacy classes). From there it is not a great leap to define the second FC center and so on, but I am not aware of any significant study of these concepts.

The answers to Q1 and Q2 are both positive and use a simple observation. Suppose $N_1 \le N_2$ are normal subgroups of $G$ and consider the natural map $G/N_1 \to G/N_2$. Then the FC-center of $G/N_1$ maps into the FC-center of $G/N_2$. Indeed, if an element has a finite conjugacy class modulo $N_1$ then it certainly does so modulo the larger group $N_2$.

**Q1:** Let me write $F(G)$ for the FC-center and $F^\alpha(G)$ for the iterated variants. Let $N = \bigcup_\alpha F^\alpha(G)$ be the limit of the whole process. Then $N$ is a characterstic subgroup of $G$, as is $F^\alpha(N)$ for all $\alpha$. I claim inductively that $F^\alpha(G) \le F^\alpha(N)$ for all $\alpha$. The induction is obvious for zero and limit ordinals, and the case of successor ordinals follows from the observation above applied to $N/F^\alpha(G) \to N / F^\alpha(N)$.

**Q2:** Suppose $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $G/H$ is ICC. I claim that $F^\alpha(G) \le H$ for all $\alpha$. Again it suffices to a consider a successor ordinal $\alpha+1$, and now we apply the observation above to $G / F^\alpha(G) \to G/H$, noting that $F(G/H)=1$.

In light of Q2, an alternative name for the "hyper FC center" might be the "ICC residual". It is the smallest normal subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ is ICC.